# Django, code inside <script> tag doesn't work in a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm trying to use **Bootstrap File Input** in my django application. I've loaded all necessary files in header. Here is my form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
 <input id="file1" name="file1[]" class ="file" type="file" multiple="multiple">
<div>
</form>
```

**Bootstrap File Input** works fine. But I need to configure some options. In tutorial and examples its looks like that:

```
<script>
$('#file1').fileinput({
  showUpload: false,
});   
</script>
```

Code inside the **script** tag doesn't work. Any script in this tag doesn't work. Tried to use **$(document).ready(function(){})** in the beggining, but without result. What can be wrong with it? Script goes after form.

Comment: sounds like there is a conflict with $. Have you tried jQuery('#file1').fileinput({....etc etc?

Comment: do you see any errors in the javascript console?  do you see jquery and bootstrap js files loaded in the network tab?

Comment: Thank you for your answears. There is no errors in the js console and jquery & bootstrap files loaded fine. I've tried jQuery('#file1').fileinput({ ....etc and it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this :

```
<input id="file1" name="file1[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $("#file1").fileinput({
        showUpload: false,
    });
});
</script>
```